# Counting child nodes using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, parsing, dom

I've some XML that I want to count the number of products it contains information about...but struggling to get the right syntax, here's my code...

```
Dim XMLHttpRequest As XMLHTTP60
Set XMLHttpRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Dim objxmlSKU As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim SKUCount As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim objxmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim count As Integer

XMLHttpRequest.Open "GET", signedURL, False
XMLHttpRequest.send (signedURL)
objxmldoc.loadXML (XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML)

xmlNamespaces =    "xmlns:ns1='https://mws.amazonservices.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01'"
objxmldoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespaces

Set SKUCount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//ns1:InventorySupplyList/ns1:member") 

count = 0
For Each member In SKUCount
    count = count + 1
Next
Debug.Print count
```

& here's the sample XML (I wish to count the number of blocks headed up with member ...therefore in the following code there are two blocks with the XML name member..

```
<ListInventorySupplyResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01/">
    <ListInventorySupplyResult>
        <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
        <InventorySupplyList>
            <member>
                <Condition>NewItem</Condition>
                <SupplyDetail/>
                <TotalSupplyQuantity>43</TotalSupplyQuantity>
                <EarliestAvailability>
                    <TimepointType>Immediately</TimepointType>
                </EarliestAvailability>
                <FNSKU>B005H38BZ4</FNSKU>
                <InStockSupplyQuantity>43</InStockSupplyQuantity>
                <ASIN>B005H38BZ4</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>dtp-11 fba</SellerSKU>
            </member>
            <member>
                <Condition>NewItem</Condition>
                <SupplyDetail/>
                <TotalSupplyQuantity>40</TotalSupplyQuantity>
                <EarliestAvailability>
                    <TimepointType>Immediately</TimepointType>
                </EarliestAvailability>
                <FNSKU>B01BvMUHM8</FNSKU>
                <InStockSupplyQuantity>40</InStockSupplyQuantity>
                <ASIN>B01BVMUHM8</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>dsx-90 fba</SellerSKU>
            </member>
        </InventorySupplyList>
    </ListInventorySupplyResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>8a7d1832-b271-4171-991f-7e39feee5bf1</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</ListInventorySupplyResponse>
```

Comment: The stack overflow interface/gui is very busy/ noisy...I can't even see an option to mark the question as answered!

Comment: There's a noticeable [gray check mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the left side of each answer. Click it to go green.

Answer (score 2):

Example on how to do this with your XML doc :

```vb
Public Sub Test_XML()


    Dim SKUCount As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim objxmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim count As Integer

    Dim strXML As String
    Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode


    strXML = strXML & "<ListInventorySupplyResponse>  "
    strXML = strXML & "    <ListInventorySupplyResult>                                                                  "
    strXML = strXML & "        <InventorySupplyList>                                                                    "
    strXML = strXML & "            <member>                                                                             "
    strXML = strXML & "                <Condition>NewItem</Condition>                                                   "
    strXML = strXML & "                <SupplyDetail/>                                                                  "
    strXML = strXML & "                <TotalSupplyQuantity>43</TotalSupplyQuantity>                                    "
    strXML = strXML & "                <EarliestAvailability>                                                           "
    strXML = strXML & "                    <TimepointType>Immediately</TimepointType>                                   "
    strXML = strXML & "                </EarliestAvailability>                                                          "
    strXML = strXML & "                <FNSKU>B005H38BZ4</FNSKU>                                                        "
    strXML = strXML & "                <InStockSupplyQuantity>43</InStockSupplyQuantity>                                "
    strXML = strXML & "                <ASIN>B005H38BZ4</ASIN>                                                          "
    strXML = strXML & "                <SellerSKU>dtp-11 fba</SellerSKU>                                                "
    strXML = strXML & "            </member>                                                                            "
    strXML = strXML & "            <member>                                                                             "
    strXML = strXML & "                <Condition>NewItem</Condition>                                                   "
    strXML = strXML & "                <SupplyDetail/>                                                                  "
    strXML = strXML & "                <TotalSupplyQuantity>40</TotalSupplyQuantity>                                    "
    strXML = strXML & "                <EarliestAvailability>                                                           "
    strXML = strXML & "                    <TimepointType>Immediately</TimepointType>                                   "
    strXML = strXML & "                </EarliestAvailability>                                                          "
    strXML = strXML & "                <FNSKU>B01BvMUHM8</FNSKU>                                                        "
    strXML = strXML & "                <InStockSupplyQuantity>40</InStockSupplyQuantity>                                "
    strXML = strXML & "                <ASIN>B01BVMUHM8</ASIN>                                                          "
    strXML = strXML & "                <SellerSKU>dsx-90 fba</SellerSKU>                                                "
    strXML = strXML & "            </member>                                                                            "
    strXML = strXML & "        </InventorySupplyList>                                                                   "
    strXML = strXML & "    </ListInventorySupplyResult>                                                                 "
    strXML = strXML & "    <ResponseMetadata>                                                                           "
    strXML = strXML & "        <RequestId>8a7d1832-b271-4171-991f-7e39feee5bf1</RequestId>                              "
    strXML = strXML & "    </ResponseMetadata>                                                                          "
    strXML = strXML & "</ListInventorySupplyResponse>                                                                   "
    strXML = strXML & ""


    objxmldoc.loadXML (strXML)


    Set SKUCount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//ListInventorySupplyResponse/ListInventorySupplyResult/InventorySupplyList/member")

    ' Get the number of "member" nodes:
    Debug.Print "Total member nodes : " & SKUCount.length

    count = 0
    For Each node In SKUCount
        ' Loop on "Member" nodes
        count = count + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print "Loop count = " & count

End Sub
```

outputs :

> ```
> Total member nodes : 2
> Loop count = 2
> ```

Comment: Tahnks for your input, but I'm not getting the same result (0 noceds). I can therefore this discrepancy (i.e. works for you, not for me), is down to the raw XML being used/loaded...my sample XML has extra info in the header & my code references the namespace. I'm pretty sure therefore that the reason it's not working for me is to do with the namespace & likely the path I'm using in the Set SKUCount = objxmldoc.selectNodes

Comment: Ok, I have it working, the bit that I needed was this....  Set SKUCount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//ns1:member") .....so it was a path problem....thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

When using `selectNodes` you need to specify the XPath with the nodes names as they occur in the document, so without the `ns1:` prefix:

```
 Set SKUCount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//InventorySupplyList/member")
```

Then the loop will work and return a count of 2.

If you want to get the count without the loop, you can use the [`length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd873682(v=vs.85).aspx) property:

```
Debug.Print SKUCount.length
```

Comment: I tried Set SKUCount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//InventorySupplyList/member") ...but still got a result of 0 nodes ...I think it's to do with the path.

Comment: Ok, I have it working, the bit that I needed was this....  Set SKUCount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//ns1:member") .....so it was a path problem....thanks for your help